# Holoviews - create histogram next to datashader plot

Tags: python, dataframe, holoviews, datashader

I have a pandas dataframe, `data` from which I would like to create a datashader plot with a histogram next to it. I get the datashader plot to work but when I try to add the histogram it is not working anymore. What I am doing is the following:

- My dataframe is like this:

|  | column |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-30 22:00:00+00:00 | 101.4 |
| 2022-04-30 22:03:00+00:00 | 259.5 |

- The code I am using to do the datashade plot is as follows:

```
scatter_dict, hist_dict = hv_elements(data, flag="app", colors=colors, num_bins=500, y_range=y_range, 
kind=kind)

curve_overlay = hv.NdOverlay(scatter_dict, kdims='cols')

ds_curve_overlay = dynspread(datashade(curve_overlay,
                          aggregator=ds.count_cat('cols'),
                          y_range=y_range,
                          color_key=colors)).opts(
                height=height,
                title=title,
                xlabel=xlabel,
                ylabel=ylabel,
                xrotation=xrotation,
                active_tools=active_tools,
                hooks=[hv_dateformatter],
                responsive=responsive,
                **kwargs)
```

Which is working fine.

- Now, to add the histogram, I do the following:

```
lnk_sel = link_selections.instance()

h = hv.NdOverlay(hist_dict)

h.opts(width=hist_width,
                       height=height,
                       xrotation=xrotation,
                       xlabel='',
                       ylabel=ylabel,
                       )
```

- And I put together both plots:

```
dmap = (ds_curve_overlay).opts(height=height)
linked_dmap = lnk_sel(dmap + h)
return linked_dmap
```

However, every time I try to add the histogram it doesn't work...
Does anybody see why I am having this problem?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: It's hard to see how to debug that without the dataset or the code for e.g. hv_elements. If you edit it to create the dataset (e.g. with a numpy random distribution) and also include the hv_elements code (in as simple a form as possible) it is more likely that someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem I had by doing a panel with both plots:

```
panel = pn.Row(linked_dmap, h)
return panel.servable()
```